# openiddict - Using ListAsync method on IOpenIddictScopeStore

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver, openiddict

I am using openiddict library from https://github.com/openiddict.
I need to list all the scopes where display name matches specified filter criteria on request to api. However, I can't figure out how to consume the ListAsync method on [IOpenIddictScopeManager](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/src/OpenIddict.Abstractions/Managers/IOpenIddictScopeManager.cs) .

Method signature is :

```
 IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> ListAsync<TResult>(
        Func<IQueryable<**object**>,IQueryable<TResult>> query, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

Scope manager uses a store internally and delegate calls to it.
[IOpenIddictScopeStore.cs](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/src/OpenIddict.Abstractions/Stores/IOpenIddictScopeStore.cs)

Method signature is :

```
IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> ListAsync<TState, TResult>(
        Func<IQueryable<**TScope**>, TState, IQueryable<TResult>> query,
        TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

Implementation for the MongDB store  can be located at [OpenIddictMongoDbScopeStore](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/src/OpenIddict.MongoDb/Stores/OpenIddictMongoDbScopeStore.cs).

**Update**

I am able to get it working with SQL store :

```
    Func<IQueryable<object>, IQueryable<object>> query =
                  (scopes) => scopes.Where(s => (s as OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreScope).DisplayName.StartsWith(request.ScopesFilter)
                    );
await scopeManager.ListAsync<object>(query, CancellationToken.None)
```

However, same thing won't work for MONGO store.

```
Func<IQueryable<object>, IQueryable<object>> query =
                      (scopes) => scopes.Where(s => (s as OpenIddictMongoDbScope).DisplayName.StartsWith(request.ScopesFilter)
                        );
    await scopeManager.ListAsync<object>(query, CancellationToken.None)
```

The mongo store  fails with below exceptions

a. when using above query with CountAsync(query)

"Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryableImpl`2[OpenIddict.MongoDb.Models.OpenIddictMongoDbScope,System.Object]' to type 'MongoDB.Driver.Linq.IMongoQueryable`1[OpenIddict.MongoDb.Models.OpenIddictMongoDbScope]'."

b. when using above query with ListAsync(query)

Unable to cast object of type 'AsyncStateMachineBox`1[MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursor`1[OpenIddict.MongoDb.Models.OpenIddictMongoDbScope],MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1+<UsingImplicitSessionAsync>d__106`1[OpenIddict.MongoDb.Models.OpenIddictMongoDbScope,MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursor`1[OpenIddict.MongoDb.Models.OpenIddictMongoDbScope]]]' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursor`1[System.Object]]'. at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with MongoDb driver. I upgraded MongDb driver binaries to a recent version and the query started working as expected.